# Feature file 'scenario outline' data array item not being picked by in Step Definition

Tags: intellisense

I set up a Feature File with a scenario outline, but then I can not use the data array item in my step definition file.

i.e. 'address' is my feature file data array item, 
but in my step definition file, 'address' is underlined by Eclipse IntelliSense as an error and this gives an 'Arity mismatch' message if run.

I am new to automation and want my step definition to pick up the Feature File scenario outline array data. 
Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

```
Feature: Login
Scenario Outline: Successful login
Given HomePage '<address>'
When ValidCredentials
Then LoginSuccessfull

Examples:
|address|
|https://totaljobs.com|


//Step Definition extract 
@Given("HomePage '(.*?)'")
public void HomePage() {
driver.get(address);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1536, 792));
System.out.println("Chrome opened");
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println("Current url:" +url);
}
```

Comment: Using Cucumber Gherkin